# Why Am I Getting a 304 Response Code For This Image Request?

Tags: http, response

I routinely upload a number of images to a web site, either by HTML form or FTP to the same target location. For one particular image, I get a 304 when I access it via browser. It seems just like the other images. Can anyone provide a guess as to why?

https://www.danzeffguitars.com/images/classical/smalls/Picado-2015-small-front1.jpg

Doesn't matter if it's HTTP or HTTPS. All the other images I have uploaded render fine in the browser and return a 200. What could possibly be different? Thanks.

Comment: [Do you know what a 304 means?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)

Comment: I do. It means the client (my browser) already has a cached copy, so the response is redirecting it to use its local copy. However, no such copy resides with any of my browsers. I've tried many on different machines, including those who have never visited the site.